# Types of output that will work for a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am currently working on a small nodejs project that is responsible for returning search terms from a twitter feed. I have the search working however because I am new to this I am having problems displaying this on my webpage. The search information I want to display is being held by a callback from my function and I want to output this information. Keep in mind this information is ascertained after the webpage is loaded and I think that is why response.write(information); is not working for me. However if I do console.log(information); I do get the information I want but it's just not where I want it. Can someone help me out with outputting please.

I ended up solving this by using JSON.stringify(information);

Comment: If you post your code and exactly explain what the problem is, then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's very likely that once you have returned your webpage the response will be closed.

2 options:

1) you load your webpage first on 1 static route (using static middleware) and this web page then does an ajax call to a second route which returns your information.

2) you don't return your webpage until you have retrieved your information. I'm assuming your information will need to be displayed on this webpage which means you'll have to turn your webpage in a template and merge it with your information. You can use a Jade template or underscore template for example.

Comment: Thanks this si what I was looking for, don't really understand what was unclear about my questions but whatever. Thanks for the help